# Hugo content not rendering

Tags: hugo

I've used the [hugo-icon](https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/hugo-icon/) single page theme to build a static site and have been asked to add a new page for product descriptions.  I have read many tutorials/answers on stack and watched [Mike Danes videos](https://www.mikedane.com/static-site-generators/hugo/) to date but cannot get a new page to render.

When I run the following command `hugo new products/product1/_index.md` a url to product1 is generated but no content is rendered.  This is the content of my _index.md file;

```
---
title: "Product1"
date: 2021-05-24T14:47:36+01:00
draft: false
---
product1 info
```

I expect one of 2 things;  To see 'product1 info' rendered at the url.  OR I place a html file of the same name somewhere in the folder structure to render text etc.  I have tried multiple locations to place html and still I cannot see anything.

Can someone explain or give an example of adding a new page to the hugo-icon theme and explain if I am missing a fundamental concept.

config:

```
# Main config file for icon theme.
theme = ["hugo-icon"]
baseURL = "https://www.example.com/"
languageCode = "en-ie"
title = "my site"

[params]
  author = "Me"
  description = "My site"

# Hero section (from here on is for icon theme)
[params.hero]
  img = "images/hero_bg_green.jpg"
  title = "My Site"
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to verify when you are browsing localhost, you went to localhost:1313/products/product1/ and nothing was rendered? Can you send through your config? (config.toml or yaml, etc. in case their are some ) Also can you confirm what server flags you used? (hugo server -D etc...)

Comment: @Rogelio, correct on the localhost path. Im serving with `hugo server -D` and have tried with draft:false in the toml file. Config snippet is above;
[adding pages seems supported](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-icon/#adding-additional-pages) 

Thanks, R

Comment: Sorry I'm so slow here, maybe make a safe access to your repo (or copy the repo where you feel comfortable) and site deployment. I made a local instance and this worked just fine, so I'd need to check how you set it up/the config.

Comment: Thanks, did you link it to the menu in the single page setup? I was trying to link a url in a new route when I click a button rather than on the same page.  I spoke with the theme author on twitter and it's intended as a single page setup so I'm probably fighting against the tide.  If you managed to build a rendered page outside of the root let me know.  If not I'll close this Q.  Thanks for the help @Rogelio

Answer (score 2):

I was missing this fundamental design pattern.  Each folder created under layouts required a template.  In my case this looked like the following where each page was designed inside the single.html file

```
Layouts
 page1
  single.html
 page2
  single.html
```

The route needs defining in the content folder inside content/pages/page-one.md like so where type is mapped to the folder name by its type definition

```
type : "page1"

title: "Page 1"

date: 2021-05-27T11:16:39+01:00

draft: false
```

My url therefore is [www.example.com/pages/page-one.html](http://www.example.com/pages/page-one.html) which is designed in layouts/page1/single.html and mapped via the type definition to [www.example.com/content/pages/page-one.md](http://www.example.com/content/pages/page-one.md)

The .md file inside content/... dictates the path to the url.  The type definition dictates which page to render from layouts/...